# Terraform: changing a list of variables into one list of maps

Tags: terraform

I have 3 terraform variables which are lists.

```
container_ports = [5000, 5001]
container_names = ["image1", "image2"]
load_balancer_arns = ["lb1", "1b2"]
```

How do I change the structure into a list of maps like below?

```
ecs_service_lb_config = [
   {
    container_port = 5000
    container_name = "image1"
    load_balancer_arn = "lb1
   },{
    container_port = 5001
    container_name = "image2"
    load_balancer_arn = "lb2
   }
]
```

Comment: Apart from the obvious define the variable? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are empowered to change the interface of this module then I would suggest addressing the problem at its root by redefining the variable to arrive as the list of objects you need it to be:

```
variable "ecs_service_load_balancers" {
  type = list(object({
    container_port    = number
    container_name    = string
    load_balancer_arn = string
  }))
}
```

Note that this is a list of objects rather than a list of maps, because we're specifying specific attributes that are required rather than just calling for arbitrary key/value pairs chosen by the caller.

The caller of the module would then specify this using the same syntax you showed in your question:

```
module "example" {
  # ...

  ecs_service_load_balancers = [
    {
      container_port    = 5000
      container_name    = "image1"
      load_balancer_arn = "lb1
    },
    {
      container_port    = 5001
      container_name    = "image2"
      load_balancer_arn = "lb2"
    },
  ]
}
```

An advantage of this structure is that it's clearer which attribute values belong to which of the objects; the reader of the call doesn't need to carefully correlate by index to understand which is which.

---

If you cannot change the interface of this module but you still want these collected together into a list of objects internally *within* the module then you can create the same data structure programmatically based on the individual variable values.

```
variable "container_ports" {
  type = list(number)
}

variable "container_names" {
  type = list(string)
}

variable "load_balancer_arns" {
  type = list(string)
}

locals {
  ecs_service_load_balancers = tolist([
    for i, n in var.container_names : {
      container_port    = var.container_ports[i]
      container_name    = var.container_names[i]
      load_balancer_arn = var.load_balancer_arns[i]
    }
  ])
}
```

This uses a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) over one of the variables (I chose `var.container_names` arbitrarily, but it doesn't actually matter) and specifies `i, n` as the local symbols so that `i` will be the list index. The body of the `for` expression can then use `i` to index into all three of the lists, relying on the fact that they should always be the same length and always have correlated items.

I needed to declare symbol `n` because it's always required to declare a symbol for the current element value, but I didn't use it inline because I wrote out `var.container_names[i]` instead to get the same value in a way that's consistent with the other two attribute definitions, in the hope of it being easier for a future reader to understand the goal of this expression.

You can then use `local.ecs_service_load_balancers` to get a similar list of objects as would be produced by the single list of objects variable declaration I showed above.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach can be:

```
ecs_service_lb_config = [
 {
   container_port = element(container_port, 0)
   container_name = element(container_name, 0)
   load_balancer_arn = element(load_balancer_arn, 0)
 },{
   container_port = element(container_port, 1)
   container_name = element(container_name, 1)
   load_balancer_arn = element(load_balancer_arn, 1)
 }
]
```

The problem here that is not a auto scalable code, because if you need to add more elements you need to add a new block into the map.
I'm looking for a better solution, but this could be a quick fix.

But if idk why are you using 3 differente variables if you can give me a better context maybe i can give you a cleanest solution.